# Is there a regex way to detect whether a character can be part of a word or not?

Tags: regex, vb.net

The "tricky" part of this question is that what I mean by alphabeth is not just the 26 characters. It should also include anything alphabeth like, including accented characters and hebrew's alibeth, etc.etc.

Why I need them?

I want to split texts into words.

Alphabeths like latin alphabeth, hebrew's alibeth, arab abjads, are separated by space.

Chinese characters are separated by nothing.

So I think I should separate texts by anything that's not alphabeth.

In other word, a, b, c, d, é is fine.

駅,南,口,第,自,転,車.,3,5,6 is not and all such separator should be it's own words. Or stuff like that.

In short I want to detect whether a character may be a **word** by itself, or **can be part of a word**.

What have I tried?

Well you can check the question here I asked a long time ago:
[How can we separate utf-8 characters into words if some of the characters are chinese?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412544/how-can-we-separate-utf-8-characters-into-words-if-some-of-the-characters-are-ch/12412586#comment17271993_12412586)

I implement the only answer there but then I found out that the chinese characters aren't split. Why not split based on nothing? Well, that means the alphabeths are splitted too.

If all those alphabeths "stick" together that I can separate them based on UTF, that would be fine too.

I will just use the answer at [How can we separate utf-8 characters into words if some of the characters are chinese?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412544/how-can-we-separate-utf-8-characters-into-words-if-some-of-the-characters-are-ch/12412586#comment17271993_12412586)
 and "pull out" all non alphabeth characters.

Not a perfect solution, but good enough for me because western characters and chinese characters rarely show up on the same text anyway.

Comment: To check if a string contains just Alpha chars (i.e A-Z) - The Regex will be "^[a-zA-Z]*$"

Comment: I gotta ask: what have you tried?

Comment: That one is easy. I want to be able to match  é  too. Also all hebrew characters and all arab characters.

Comment: What have I tried? Okay hang on :D

Comment: Added things I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't do this with regular expressions but with good old string index scanning instead.

The Hebrew, Chinese, Korean etc. alphabets are all in consecutive ranges of unicode code-points. So you could easily detect the alphabet by reading the unicode value of the character and then checking which unicode block it belongs to.

Comment: I've been thinking of the same idea too. What about the accent? Do they stick together too?

Comment: And being a little lazy, is there someone that have lists of ranged of alphabets already :) currently ascw doesn't map all utf8 character right?

Comment: I need to wait 3 minutes to accept answer. Awesome thanks a lot Phillipp

Answer (score 1):

Jan Goyvaerts (of PowerGrep fame) once showed me this very useful syntax to do just this:

```
(?<![\p{M}\p{L}])word(?![\p{M}\p{L}])
```

This expression uses a regex lookbehind and a regex lookahead to ensure that the boundaries of the word are such that there is no letter or diacritic mark on either side.

Why is this regex better than simply using "\b"? The strength of this regex is the incorporation of \p{M} to include diacritics. When the normal word boundary marker (\b) is used, regex engines will find word breaks at the places of many diacritics, even though the diacritics are actually part of the word (this is the case, for instance, with Hebrew diacritics. For an example, take the Hebrew word גְּבוּלוֹת, and run a regex of "\b." on it - you'll see how it actually breaks the word into word different parts, at each diacritic point). The regex above fixes this by using a Unicode Character Class to ensure that diacritics are always considered part of the word and not breaks within the word.

Comment: And this work with chinese character? Oh it breaks on every non alphabeth character?

Comment: @Jim - no source; it emerged from a private conversation I had with Jan.